# Getting S3_REGION for AWS S3 image upload in Golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I wanted to upload an image in aws s3.

```
const (
    S3_REGION = ""
    S3_BUCKET = ""
)

func main() {

    // Create a single AWS session (we can re use this if we're uploading many files)
    s, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(S3_REGION)})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Upload
    err = AddFileToS3(s, "result.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I am stuck here.
Where can I get S3_REGION as per this code standard?
Source : https://golangcode.com/uploading-a-file-to-s3/

Comment: It should be set to whatever region your bucket is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you log in to the AWS console you see on the top right which region you are logged in to, for example "Oregon" which refers to the "us-west-2" region.

[image: AWS Region Codes]

Please refer to [this table](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/) and this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html).